# how to stop a for loop within a range of numbers

Tags: python

I have a range from 1000 - 1500, i have to find the first 3 prime numbers in that range. I have the code that finds every prime number from 1000-1500 but i just don't know how to stop at the first 3. Sorry if this may sound stupid

```
def is_prime_number(x):
    if x >= 2:
        for y in range(2, x):
            if not (x % y):
                return False
    else:
        return False
    return True


for i in range(1000,1500):
    if is_prime_number(i):
       print(i)


Expected:
1009
1013
1019
```

Comment: You should count the found number (with a counter variable) and break the loop when the count is 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `break` keyword. While in a `for` loop, the [`break`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) keyword will break out of it. Keep track of the number of primes you've found with a counter, like below:

```
count = 0
for i in range(1000,1500):
    if is_prime_number(i):
        print(i)
        count += 1
        if count == 3:
            break
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code. It maintains a prime_count variable to keep track of how many prime numbers have been calculated and breaks, when the count is 3.

```
prime_count = 0
for i in range(1000,1500):
    if is_prime_number(i):
       prime_count += 1
       print(i)

    if prime_count == 3:
        break
```